# Error using strcmp within fittype

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, strcmp, model-fitting

I just received a script from a colleague whose first line is this:

```
VonMisesModel=fittype(@(A,k,base,peakloc,x) (base + A*exp(k*cos((pi/180)*(x-peakloc)))/(2*besseli(0,k)*pi)),'independent','x');
```

He's done a good deal of processing with this script, so I'd imagine this line of code works for him.

However, when I call it, I get the following error:

```
>> VonMisesModel=fittype(@(A,k,base,peakloc,x) (base + A*exp(k*cos((pi/180)*(x-peakloc)))/(2*besseli(0,k)*pi)),'independent','x');

Error using strcmp
The number of rows of the string matrix must match the number of elements in the cell.

Error in cell/ismember (line 38)
    match = strcmp(a,b);

Error in fittype>iTestAnonymousFunctionArgumentOrder (line 786)
[~, coefficientLocations] = ismember( obj.coeff, arguments );

Error in fittype>iCreateFromAnonymousFunction (line 533)
iTestAnonymousFunctionArgumentOrder( obj, theFcn )

Error in fittype>iCreateFittype (line 355)
obj = iCreateFromAnonymousFunction( obj, varargin{:} );

Error in fittype (line 328)
            obj = iCreateFittype( obj, varargin{:} );
```

I'd like to reiterate that this is the first line in a stand-alone script.  No processing is meant to occur before this line is called.

The error does not seem intuitive to me at all.  My guesses at what might have caused it have not turned up a solution.  Does anyone know why this error was raised?

## Edit

The definition of the `fittype` function appears to have changed over time.

The error in the question is raised when I use versions of Matlab newer than `matlab-2012a`.

However, the error is *not* raised when I use `matlab-2012a`.

My pre-2012 `matlab` distributions do not contain the function `fittype` at all.

**In order for other functions in this script to work, I need to get this call to `fittype` to work with new(er) versions of Matlab.  If you can, please let me know how to rearrange the call to prevent the error.**

Comment: I suggest you trawl through the built-in functions and identify which strings that causes the error. It's either `a` or `b`, thus either `obj.coeff / arguments`, `obj` seems to go all the way back to `fittype`, while `arguments` is defined within `iCreateFromAnonymousFunction` somewhere. I don't know if this will help debug the problem, but it might be worth a try... :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin yeah, i guess that will be my last resort.  hopefully someone familiar with `fittype` who knows how to correct my call signature will come by before i have to do that.

Comment: so, it turns out for my particular case that i don't need to call `fittype` here -- i can just use the anonymous function itself.  my colleague thinks the error may be due to `fittype` needing to identify something to fit, and since we're not using it to fit in this context -- all the parameters are supplied -- it throws a fit.

Comment: You might post _that_ as an answer. :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin naa, it should be left for someone w/ more knowledge to explain exactly what's wrong (and why earlier versions do not raise an error).

Comment: On the [MATLAB doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html) it says "Introduced before R2006a", so how come you can't see it before 2012?

Comment: @EBH yes, i saw that. i don't know.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the "Curve Fitting Toolbox"?

Comment: @EBH could be that i have it for some versions and not others, i guess, on my shared computing cluster.